# Mean Value in cell array MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mean, cell-array

I have generated a cell array of 1x5 cells with  a 10x1 column vector on each cell.

How can I find the average of all the column vectors? So to have a final 10x1 new column vector that contains the means.  Thank you

Comment: Please post the code that generates this cell array. Regardless, you should stay away from cells in this case, and just generate a numeric array of size 10x5, then `mean(...,2)` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would concatenate the cell array contents along the second dimension (using `cat` and `{:}` indexing to get a comma separated list) and then take the mean along this first dimension

```
result = mean(cat(2, data{:}));
```

Since your data is purely numeric, you should avoid cell arrays and instead deal with a `5 x 10` matrix as that will be much more performant. You can easily create that the same way we did above.

```
matrix_data = cat(2, data{:});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy solution:

```
mean([A{:}])   % column-wise mean (1x5)
mean([A{:}],2) % row-wise mean    (10x1)
```

Comment: That's a nice solution too. Thanks!